# VSCode の Pug で class 名を補完したい

Tags: vscode, pug

**発生している問題**

VSCode での開発に Pug を使用しています。
cssのクラス名を入力時に補完したいのですが、何か方法はないでしょうか。

htmlやjsxでの補完が効くものはありますが、pugに対応しているものがみつかりません。HTML CSS Supportが対応しているような表記がありますが、インストールしたものの結局動作せず、ホストしているGitHubにもそのようなissueが上がっていませんでした。

**環境**

- Windowns 10 (64bit)
- VSCode: insiders 1.53.0

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

HTML CSS Support が動作しなかったので、バージョンが新しくなったのが原因みたいでした。
0.2.3 へダウングレードすることで正常に動作しました。